# Theme Options Page - User Updates Logo

Tags: php, theme-development, css, theme-options, logo

I'm a newbie to WordPress Development so bear with me.

Site: https://wordpress-portfolio-zacnespral21.c9.io/

On the site above I would like to add an option in the themes options page for the user to replace the brid logo(default) on the left hand side with whatever image they choose/upload. I was able to get the themes option page created and fill in some dummy content, but now im stuck. Currently the logo is being called via background-image on a span with the class of .portfolioLogo any help to get this working would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
<?php

/**
* Step 1: Create link to the menu page.
*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'ss_create_menu');
function ss_create_menu() {    
    //create new top-level menu
    add_menu_page(__('Theme Settings', 'simpleandsweet'), __('S&S Theme', 'simpleandsweet'), 'administrator', 'simpleandsweet-theme-settings', 'ss_settings_page', 'dashicons-admin-generic');   
}

/**
* Step 2: Create settings fields.
*/
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_znsettings' );
function register_znsettings() {
    register_setting( 'ss-settings-general', 'portfolioLogo' );
}

/** 
* Step 3: Create the markup for the options page
*/
function ss_settings_page() {

?>

<div class="wrap">
<h2><?php _e('Simple and Sweet - Theme Settings', 'S&S Themes'); ?></h2>

    <form method="post" id="ss-theme-options" action="options.php">

        <?php if(isset( $_GET['settings-updated'])) { ?>
        <div class="updated">
            <p><?php _e('Settings updated successfully', $textdomain); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <table class="form-table">
            <tr><td colspan="2"><h3><?php _e('Current Site Logo', 'simpleandsweet'); ?></h3></td></tr>

            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><?php _e('Logo', 'simpleandsweet'); ?></th>
                <td>
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php settings_fields( 'ss-settings-general' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'ss-settings-general' ); ?>
        </table>

        <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

what framework do you use for your theme-panel?

You need to make image upload into your theme panel page and a line of code to call it everywhere of your theme you want.

This is an example:

in theme panel `function page`

```
$options[] = array(
        'name' => __('Introduction Image', 'options_check'),
        'desc' => __('This is your site logo.', 'options_check'),
        'id' => 'introtext_uploader',
        'type' => 'upload');
```

and into your theme e.g `header.php`

```
<img src="<?php echo of_get_option('introtext_uploader'); ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: Im confused when you say "What framework do I use" so ive updated my question with the code from my theme-options page, i tried what you said but i dont believe i did it right, so im giving you the code that currently works instead.